# Number Theory And Divisibility

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Suppose $a,b,c,d$ are positive integers greater than $3$ such that $a^b$ divides $b^c$, $b^c$ divides $c^d$, $c^d$ divides $d^a$. Prove that it is not possible to find the smallest of the numbers $a,b,c,d$
$$$$ Let us asume that $a$ be the smallest among $a,b,c,d$ then as $c^d$ divides $d^a$ it must divide $d^c$ as $c>a$ so we get $$c^d \leq d^c \implies c^{\frac{1}{c}} \leq d^{\frac{1}{d}} \implies c > d$$ as we know that $x^{\frac{1}{x}}$ is a decreasing function for $x>3$
$$$$ Now as $b^c$ divides $c^d$ and as $c>d$ so we get $b^c$ divides $c^c$ so $b^c \leq c^c \implies b \leq c$
$$$$ Also we have $b^c$ divides $d^a$ so $b^d$ divides $d^a$ as $d < c$ so $b^d$ divides $d^b$ as $d > a$ so $$b^d \leq d^b \implies b^{\frac{1}{b}} \leq d^{\frac{1}{d}} \implies d < b$$
Also we have $a^b$ divides $d^a$ so that implies $a^d$ divides $d^a$ as $d > a$ so we get $$a^d \leq d^a \implies a^{\frac{1}{a}} \leq d^{\frac{1}{d}} \implies a > d$$ A Contradiction and Similarly if we assume any of $a, b, c, d$ as the smallest we will arrive at the contradiction so it is not possilble to find the smallest of the given numbers
$$$$ Is The Proof Correct?

Comment: I'd say the idea is correct, but the presentation is chaotic, from the very beginning, i.e the statement of the problem: *Prove that it is not possible to find the smallest of the numbers*. What exactly does this mean? I think the proper statement is *Prove that they are all equal*. Your idea of proof should still work, but you have to pay attention to the differences of $<$ vs $\leq$, and $>$ vs $\geq$.